# How to query for an association of an association in Rails with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models and associations:

- **Organizations** which `has_many` **Recipes**
- **Recipes** `has_many` **Tags**

I'm trying to get all of the tags associated with all recipes of an organization. I want to do something like, `Organization.find(1).recipes.tags`, but it's not working. Is there an easier way to query for this, rather than looping through each recipe to collect it's tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use joins and filter on `organization_id`

```
Tag.joins(recipies: :organization).where('recipies.organization_id' => 1)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. I also just realized I could add this to my Organization model: 

`has_many :recipe_tags, through: :recipes, source: :tags`.

Is there a preferred "Rails way" between this and your answer? Thanks!

Comment: It's OK to use `has_many :through`, it's the rails way indeed. As many things in the rails way it can bring you too much coupling between your models.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Tag.where(recipe: Organization.find(1).recipes)
```

This assumes `Tag belongs_to :recipe`.

Comment: It does 3 querie - one for `Organization.find`, one for `Organization#recipies` and one for `Tag.where`, it's basically an app-level join and it's inefficient.

Comment: It's two queries. Perhaps you meant `Tag.where(recipe: Organization.where(id: 1).includes(:recipes))` jvillian?

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem with answering from mobile. I think we can all agree starting from `Tag` is better than starting from `Organization` which is the fundamental point.